# The metric space containing a compact subset is separable

Tags: general-topology

Let (X,d) be a metric space and K be a cpt subset of X.
If it is possible to derive 'X is compact', then since compact metric space is separable, X is separable. But I'm not sure that X is compact.
Do I have to prove that X is compact?, or Is there another method I don't know?

Comment: Just because $X$ has a compact subspace does not mean that $X$ is itself compact.  For example, take $(X,d)=(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$, the real line with the Euclidean metric.  Here, $[0,1]$ is a compact subspace, but certainly $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Comment: Yes, it's very helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, $\Bbb R$ is *not* compact in the usual metric, and $[0,1]$ is compact. The claim is certainly false in general, since any singleton is compact in any metric space of your liking, but there exist non-separable metric spaces.

Comment: Yes, if X=(R, discrete topology), then X is a metric space and {a} is compact for any a in X, but X is not separable, right?